# Most frequent time given multiple values for time in R

Tags: r, time

I want to find the average time for each user to play a song given a list of times for song plays for different users.

```
user  time                 action
A     2013-03-25T14:12:24Z PLAY
B     2013-03-28T14:54:30Z LIKE
C     2013-04-18T18:51:10Z LIKE
D     2013-05-07T18:06:24Z PLAY
B     2013-04-23T12:18:41Z PLAY
D     2013-04-29T12:00:16Z PLAY
A     2013-03-27T12:09:37Z PLAY
A     2013-04-16T18:31:44Z PLAY
```

I only want to include times where action equals PLAY.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes I want to get each users average time to play a song? Not sure if average is the best way to do it though!

Comment: You will get many people more eager to help you if you post a reproducible example. Your comment doesn't match with the text in your question. "Most frequent time" sounds like some sort of tabulation, which is different from what I think of when I read "average time to play a song". Also, instead of clarifying in the comments, you should just edit your question to make it more precise.

Comment: What do you mean by "average time to play a song" ? Do you mean the hour of the day ??

Comment: Because you are new on SO, start by reading the [**first help page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Include details about what you have tried. Don't ask about...[q]uestions you haven't tried to find an answer for (**show your work!**)". Then please continue reading [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns the average hour (of the day) in which each user plays a song:

```
DF <- 
read.csv(text=
"user,time,action
A,2013-03-25T14:12:24Z,PLAY
B,2013-03-28T14:54:30Z,LIKE
C,2013-04-18T18:51:10Z,LIKE
D,2013-05-07T18:06:24Z,PLAY
B,2013-04-23T12:18:41Z,PLAY
D,2013-04-29T12:00:16Z,PLAY
A,2013-03-27T12:09:37Z,PLAY
A,2013-04-16T18:31:44Z,PLAY",stringsAsFactors=F)

# filter by PLAY
plays <- DF[DF$action == "PLAY",]

# create means by user
byRes <- 
by(plays, plays$user,
   FUN=function(grp){
        dates <- as.POSIXlt(grp$time,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
        data.frame(user=grp$user[1],AvgHour=mean(dates$hour))
     })

# put the "by" result into a data.frame
res <- do.call(rbind,byRes)


# result :
> res
  user  AvgHour
A    A 14.66667
B    B 12.00000
D    D 15.00000
```